# Simple Ajax requests on MVC5.2 new project very slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm losing my mind trying to understand what`s wrong.

I created a new MVC5 project with identity 2.0 Authentication.
Then in index.cshtml I added after the boilerplate html:

```
<script>
    $.getJSON("/Home/GetData", function (allData) {
    });
</script>
```

In the Home Controller:

```
    public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Then launching in local the website, this request takes 3,2 seconds average.
Deploying to Azure and using all major browsers nothing changes and I have a 500Mbit internet connection and a very powerful workstation.

I can see from the dev tools that this is the Response header for the XMLHttpRequest:

```
Key Value
Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control   private
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version 5.2
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles   =?UTF-8?B?ya3NwYWNlc1xNYWtldXBweVxNYWtldXBweVxIb21lXEdldERhdGE=?=
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date    Wed, 12 Nov 2014 11:31:19 GMT
Content-Length  2
```

The response body is obviously empty ""

The timings:

```
Name               Offset       Duration    Key
Wait‎‎               0 ms         3.26 s    
Start‎‎              + 3.26 s     < 1 ms    
Request‎‎            + 3.26 s     3.17 s    
Response‎‎           + 6.43 s     < 1 ms    
Gap‎‎                + 6.43 s     < 1 ms    
DOMContentLoaded (event)‎‎  + 3.30 s    
Load (event)‎‎       + 3.35 s
```

Why it takes so much time?
I ended up doing this because in a more complex application I'm having the same problems so I wanted to see if something was wrong with the project but this is a new project almost empty.

Is the Asp.Net MVC pipeline that slow down so much even an empty ajax request?

Should I use WebAPI instead?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What scale of server are you using on Azure?

Comment: For the WebSite a Standard plan with Medium server and scale up to 10 instances. But the same timing is in localhost too it has to be something in the mvc pipeline. Is there someone that can replicate this case creating a new project and see the timings?

Comment: Have you tried MiniProfiler, might help. http://miniprofiler.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the other to come, I discovered what was the problem.

I was not using EntityFrameworkIdentity but the NuGet package ElCamino.AspNet.Identity.AzureTable that use the Azure Tables for the user identity.

I do not know what is the problem with the package, I will open an issue on the CodePlex page of this package, but as soon I remove the package and return to EntityFramework Identity the same empty XMLHttpRequest takes 90ms to execute.